# Retornar erro do PHP para o Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Estou fazer um *insert* de um campo *input* no banco de dados usando *ajax* e *PHP*. No código abaixo estou retornando para o *ajax* uma mensagem de sucesso caso tudo ocorra bem, mas como eu faço pra retornar uma mensagem caso haja algum erro?

```
function fInserir(){

            $.ajax({
                url: "php/inserirPesquisaRealizadaBanco.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {pesquisa:$("#iPesquisa").val(),dia:dia,mes:mes,ano:ano},
                success:function(ret){
                    alert(ret);

                }
            });

        }
```

---

```
$pesquisa = $_POST["pesquisa"];
$dia = $_POST["dia"];
$mes = $_POST["mes"];
$ano = $_POST["ano"];

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "prova");

mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tabelaProva(pesquisa, dData) VALUES ('$pesquisa','$ano-$mes-$dia')");
mysqli_close($conn);

echo json_encode("Sucesso");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Armazene o retorno da função `mysqli_query`. Ela irá retornar `false` em caso de erro, por exemplo:

```
$pesquisa = $_POST["pesquisa"];
$dia = $_POST["dia"];
$mes = $_POST["mes"];
$ano = $_POST["ano"];

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "prova");

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tabelaProva(pesquisa, dData) VALUES ('$pesquisa','$ano-$mes-$dia')");
mysqli_close($conn);

/**
 * Aqui usei um ternário (um `if` curto):
 * Se $result for igual a `true`, retorna "Sucesso";
 * Caso contrário, retorna "Falha"
 */
echo json_encode( ($result) ? "Sucesso" : "Falha" );
```

Mas você pode utilizar a estrutura de condição, caso acho confuso, por exemplo:

```
if ($result) {
    echo json_encode("Sucesso");
} else {
    echo json_encode("Falha");
}
```

Comment: Testei aqui e funcionou exatamente como eu queria. Obrigado pela ajuda amigo!